# Background color to child gridview's cell

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, background-color

How can i give background color to my child gridview's cell??

I have nested gridview where the cell background color could be given in rowdatabound event. But if the same has to be done for child gridview, how can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding well so i think that you need in the rowdatabound event of the parent grid to access the child gridview making an event handler for the accessed gridview.rowdatabound event and make the handler for it to change the color as you do in the parent grid.